# How to trigger a snippet of code (AMPScript or SSJS) in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I wrote a snippet of  code with AMPScript + SSJS for email, and then I'd like to trigger it when emails' status are changed, but I can`t find any way to do this like as add a 'listener' in JavaScript.

Please give me some hints if you know or did this?

Comment: When an _email_ object or _email address_ changes?  In what context?  An email or landing page?

Comment: when an email status be changed, such as Sended, Clicked, Opended, Bounce,  Unsubscribe, if these events occur then to trigger my code to update an custom object of SF.

Comment: As far as I know, there's no place in the platform for triggering on events like that.